# Fiddler reporting different response code from API to that received by the calling app

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, fiddler, http-status-code-302

I am calling an API that is hosted in Azure API management. The API is configured to use Azure Active Directory for authentication, and as such should produce a 302 redirect response when called with no authorisation header.

This is my call:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("MyApiEndPoint");
request.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", model.SubKey);

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

When I watch the call in fiddler I can indeed see the 302 redirect as the response:

[image]

However in my calling app I am getting back a 401 response.

Can anybody explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not set [`AllowAutoRedirect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `false` on your request.

The 302 is a redirect, so your request does not pass it as a response but issues a new request on the redirection resource then yields you the result of that other request.

Side note: issuing a 302 on a missing authorization may be fine for a user navigating a web page through a browser, in order to show him a custom login page. But for an API, it may be better to directly yield a 401.